# How to pass multi columns as parameters to pyspark write repartition()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have created a function that writes out a dataframe to an s3 location with some parameters. All works except for re-partition list parameter. It fails with the error: `raise TypeError("numPartitions should be an int or Column")`

The year is an int column and the date is a sate type column. When I hard-code the 2 columns as 
`.repartition("parti_create_date", "parti_hour")`  it works. 
I tried supplying them as a list, string, and col. 
Nothing seems to work.

```
parti_list = ["parti_year", "parti_create_date", "parti_hour"]
re_parti_list = ["parti_create_date", "parti_hour"]

def spark_write(in_df, write_tgt_loc, parti_list, re_parti_list, tgt_file_format, write_mode, tgt_file_compression):
(in_df
            .repartition(re_parti_list)  #(re_parti_str)
            .write
            .partitionBy(parti_str)
            .mode(write_mode).format(tgt_file_format)
            .option('compression', tgt_file_compression).option("nullValue", "null").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls,", "true")
            .save(write_tgt_loc))

spark_write(tgt_df, "s3://bucket/out/", parti_list, re_parti_list, "parquet", "overwrite","snappy")
```

Can you please help me figure out how to pass the re-partition columns as parameters in PySpark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repartition expects `either int or column`, So we need to pass `col("<col_name>")` to the dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a',),(2,'b',),(3,'c',)],['id','name'])
df.rdd.getNumPartitions() #number of partitions in df
1
```

**`Repartition on int:`**

```
df.repartition(10).rdd.getNumPartitions() #repartition to 10 

10
```

**`Repartition on columns:`**

```
df.repartition(col("id"),col("name")).rdd.getNumPartitions() #repartition on columns

200
```

**`Dynamic repartition on columns:`**

```
df.repartition(*[col(c) for c in df.columns]).rdd.getNumPartitions()

200
```

map your `columns list` to `column` type instead of **`string`** then pass the column names in **`repartition.`**

> **`For your case try this way:`**

```
df.repartition(*[col(c) for c in re_parti_list])
            .write
            .partitionBy(parti_str)
            .mode(write_mode).format(tgt_file_format)
            .option('compression', tgt_file_compression).option("nullValue", "null").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls,", "true")
            .save(write_tgt_loc))
```

**`In scala:`**

```
df.repartition(df.columns.map(c => col(c)):_*).rdd.getNumPartitions
200
```